# Posting HTML to facebook

Tags: facebook, vimeo

I recently saw a Vimeo video on facebook that had a call to action at the end that's set up in the Vimeo admin. So basically facebook is somehow allowing sharing of videos from Vimeo to play on facebook's platform through the Vimeo API,

Does anybody know how they're doing this?

Comment: In the vimeo docs it's called "Publish Videos as native posts" https://vimeo.com/business

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without looking at the Facebook post itself, but there are two possibilities:

If the video is playing in Facebook's native video player, then the page uses Vimeo's Publish to Social feature, which was released last fall: https://vimeo.com/blog/post/publish-videos-to-your-social-channels-instantly

If the video is playing with the Vimeo Player, then the video has a CTA end screen, documented here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007893267-End-screens.

Note that these features require a Vimeo PRO or Business account.